# Need computer forensic case citation (urgent)

Tags: civil-law, data-storage, legal-research, united-kingdom, digital-forensics

My mother is about to attend court over a car which was written off by a lorry.

The CCTV video recording of the accident was mishandled, such as the storage SD card not being imaged, it was also allegedly inserted into a regular computer which then corrupted the storage medium from a virus which personally I do not believe, but either way we still have not been provided with an image and we will not get one.

It would help a lot if I could provide a quote from a real court case where a DIY-er (someone with no experience attempting to collect evidence) does one of the following:

1) Damages the evidence making it useless as they tried to recover it without help of a professional

2) Even if done properly the judge is not happy that it was not done by a professional

I read a book called Computer Forensics for Dummies with the above two examples, however I have been unable to find them (probably due to stress) and am running out of time! I also tried using PDF version and searching for words to no avail.

Preferably UK law, however USA or other countries would be fine. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Does the book give any names or citations for the examples?

Comment: It's called "spoliation" in the US, and there is a lot of case law involving inexperienced people causing spoliation of evidence, regardless of type. [This may be helpful](http://dri.org/docs/default-source/dri-online/course-materials/2014/retail-and-hospitality-litigation-and-claims-management/02-preserve-your-cctv-or-else.pdf?sfvrsn=4)